# How cancel specific scheduled task?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, scheduled-tasks

If I run multiple times '/schedule' in my controller with different cronExpression in my server runs some count of tasks. How cancel specific task which was runned? For example if I schedule 3 times with different cron expression task, how cancel first or second ScheduledTask? I indetify this ScheduledTask which I must cancel? Do I need it store in some static list with some dictionary id + ScheduledTask? How it possible to provide? Thanks.

My code snippets is here.

**MyController.groovy**

```
class MyController{

  private final NotificationScheduler notificationScheduler

  @Autowired
  MyController(NotificationScheduler notificationScheduler) {
    this.notificationScheduler = notificationScheduler
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = '/schedule')
  public void Schedule(String cronExpression){

    notificationScheduler.schedule(cronExpression);
  }
  @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = '/cancel')
  public void Cancel(){
    notificationScheduler.cancel()
  }
}
```

**NotificationScheduler.groovy**

```
@Service
public class NotificationScheduler {

  private final TaskScheduler scheduler;

  @Autowired
  NotificationScheduler(TaskScheduler scheduler)
  {
    this.scheduler = scheduler
  }

  public void schedule(String cronExpression) throws ParseException {
    utilityNotifierScheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(new Notifier(), new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
  }
  public void cancel(){
    utilityNotifierScheduledFuture.cancel(false)
  }
}
```

**Notifier.groovy**

```
class Notifier implements Runnable{

  @Override
  void run() {
    System.out.println("UtilityNotifier is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
    System.out.println("Send notification");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add them to a map with a GUID, and return the GUID from the `schedule` call in `NotificationScheduler`...  Then, you can call cancel with a GUID to cancel that specific task...

Comment: @tim_yates What about if I have 1000 or 10000  or more jobs runned?